# Integrate data from several csv files using Dictionary metod

Tags: excel, dictionary, vba

I am trying to integrate data from several csv files using Dictionary approach.
Though path and other details have been checked by me carefully, running of the program is encountering error.

> Run-time error 432
> File name or class name not found during Automation operation.

This error come on the following code line `.Item(sn(j)) = GetObject("G:\OF\" & sn(j)).Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value`.

Here is my code:

```
Sub M_integratie_csv()
    sn = Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd /c Dir ""G:\OF\*.csv"" /b").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For j = 0 To UBound(sn)
            .Item(sn(j)) = GetObject("G:\OF\" & sn(j)).Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value
            GetObject("G:\OF\" & sn(j)).Close False
        Next
        Sheets.Add.Name = "total"
        For Each it In .Items
            Sheets("total").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(it), UBound(it, 2)) = it
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Links to csv files used by me are as follows.
     [csv file 1](http://1drv.ms/1UflYO4)
     [csv file 2](http://1drv.ms/1Ufm885)
     [csv file 3](http://1drv.ms/1Ufm9ZP)

Where it is going wrong?

Comment: Did you set a reference in VBE to Microsoft Scripting Runtime? Another possibility might be to break it out in two lines: `Set oDic = New Dictionary` and then `With oDic`. I tried this approach with the afore mentioned reference and it seems to work here.

Comment: I have already set reference in VBE to Microsoft Scripting Runtime, but it did not work. Your suggestion seems promising. Would you kindly send the correction on my code part so that there may not be any mismatch. It is already working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code seems to work just fine on my computer:

```
Sub M_integratie_csv()
    sn = Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd /c Dir ""G:\OF\*.csv"" /b").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
    Set oDic = New Dictionary
    With oDic
        For j = 0 To UBound(sn)
            .Item(sn(j)) = GetObject("G:\OF\" & sn(j)).Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value
            GetObject("G:\OF\" & sn(j)).Close False
        Next
        Sheets.Add.Name = "total"
        For Each it In .Items
            Sheets("total").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(it), UBound(it, 2)) = it
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Note, that the reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime must be set in the VBE in order for the above code to work.